# Is it possible to change gmail addon icons dynamically?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Is there a way for us to dynamically change our gmail-addon's icon? The one that we declare in the manifest. Just as an example, like the icons below :

[Sample Addon Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGw8Q.png)

Thank you everyone.

Comment: I am not aware of such a possibility, but you can make a feature request for it to Google! https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker

Comment: thank you @ziganotschka. I am going to file for that now.